# Area Of Polygon Whose Edges Are In Given Distance From A Given Polygon Edges

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, polygons

I'm handling a problem which I find quite difficult to solve;

My input is a changing number of coordinates (real GPS coordinates), usually I get 4-8 coordinates, and another number,which indicates a distance, let's call it $d$,while $d<0$.
Using those coordinates , I need to do the following :

First of all , I need to create a polygon. Later on , using this polygon, I need to create another polygon, with edges that are in distance $d$ from the original polygon's edges. Finally ,I need to calculate the area of the second polygon.

I'd like to know if any of you have got a solution to this problem. By solution I also mean a calculation formula or even a JS/PHP library which may handle this task.

Thanks in advnace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: [how to expand a polygon](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7844-geom2d/content/geom2d/polygons2d/expandPolygon.m)

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for the answer. What I need is to get an inner polygon of an existing one, not to expand.Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: I believe the expandPolygon function handles both cases - read the description of the function, specifically: "The input polygon POLY must be oriented counter-clockwise. Otherwise, distance is computed inside the polygon." It also states: "It is also possible to specify negative distance, and get all points inside the polygon."

Comment: BTW: Here is an algorithm to find the area of any irregular polygon: http://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html